# program crashes when getline is used to take an entire string

Tags: c++, string, function, hash

making a c++ program to implement a dictionary using hashing but while trying to take input for the meaning as an entire sentence the program crashes

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int MAX=10;
class dictionary;
class node
{
      string key,value;
      node *next;
public:
      friend class dictionary;
      node()
      {
            next=NULL;
      }
      node(string key,string value)
      {
            this->key=key;
            this->value=value;
            next=NULL;
      }
};

class dictionary
{
      node *head[MAX];
public:
      dictionary()
{
            for(int i=0;i<MAX;i++)
                  head[i]=NULL;
}
      int hashf(string word);
      void insert(string,string);
      void find(string word);
      bool deleteWord(string word);
      void display();
};
```

hash function

```
int dictionary::hashf(string word)
{
      int asciiSum=0;
      for(int i=0;i<word.length();i++)
      {
            asciiSum=asciiSum+word[i];
      }
      return (asciiSum%10);
}
```

find the word in the dictionary function

```
void dictionary::find(string word)
{
      int index=hashf(word);
      int flag=0;
      node *start=head[index];
      while(start!=NULL)
      {

            if(start->key==word)
            {
                  flag=1;
                  break;
            }
            start=start->next;
      }
      if(flag==1)
            cout<<"Word Is  present.";
      else
            cout<<"Word Is not present.";
}
```

insert into the dictionary function

```
void dictionary::insert(string word,string meaning)
{
      int index=hashf(word);
      node *p=new node(word,meaning);

      if(head[index]==NULL)
      {
            head[index]=p;
      }
      else
      {
            node *start=head[index];
            while(start->next!=NULL)
                  start=start->next;

            start->next=p;
      }

      cout<<endl<<word<<" inserted into dictionary at index"<<index;
}
```

delete from the dictionary function

```
bool dictionary::deleteWord(string word)
{
      int index=hashf(word);
      node *tmp=head[index];
      node *par=head[index];
      if(tmp==NULL) //if no word is present at that index
      {
            return false;
      }
      if(tmp->key==word && tmp->next==NULL)//only one word is present
      {
            head[index]=NULL;
            delete tmp;
            return true;
      }
      //tmp=tmp->next;
      while(tmp->key!=word && tmp->next!=NULL)
      {
            par=tmp;
            tmp=tmp->next;
      }
      if(tmp->key==word&&tmp->next!=NULL)
      {
          if(par->key==tmp->key)
          {
              head[index]=tmp->next;
          }
          else
          {
            par->next=tmp->next;
            tmp->next=NULL;
          }
            delete tmp;
            return true;
      }
      else //delete at end
      {
            par->next=NULL;
            tmp->next=NULL;
            delete tmp;
            return true;
      }
      return false;
}
```

display the entire dictionary function

```
void dictionary:: display()
{
      cout<<"\nIndex\t Key\t Value";
      for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
      {
            node *start=head[i];
            if(start==NULL)
                  cout<<"\n";
            while(start!=NULL)
            {
                  cout<<"\n:"<<i<<"\t"<<start->key <<"\t "<<start->value;
                  start=start->next;
            }
      }
}
```

main call

```
int main() {
      dictionary oxford;
      int choice;
      string word;
      string meaning;
      char ch='y';
      while(ch=='y')
      {
            cout<<"\n**** OXFORD DICTIONARY ****\n"
                        <<"1.Insert Word\n"
                        <<"2.Find Word\n"
                        <<"3.Delete Word\n"
                        <<"4.Display\n"
                        <<"Enter Your Choice :";
            cin>>choice;
            switch(choice)
            {
            case 1:
                  cout<<"Enter Word: ";
                  cin>>word;
                  cout<<"Enter Meaning: ";
                  getline(cin,meaning);
                  oxford.insert(word,meaning);

                  break;
            case 2:
                  cout<<"Enter Word to Search: ";
                  cin>>word;
                  oxford.find(word);

                  break;
            case 3:
                  cout<<"Enter Word to Delete: ";
                  cin>>word;
                  if(oxford.deleteWord(word))
                        cout<<" Word is deleted.";
                  else
                  {
                        cout<<"\nFailed to delete "<<word;
                  }
                  break;

            case 4:
                  cout<<"***Oxford Dictionary***";
                  oxford.display();
                  break;
            default:
                  cout<<"\nWrong Choice.";
            }
            cout<<"\nDo you want to continue(y/n)";
            cin>>ch;
            if(ch=='y')
            {
                continue;
            }
            else if(ch=='n')
            {
                cout<<"\nThank you for using our dictionary";
                break;
            }

      }

      return 0;
}
```

the output

```
**** OXFORD DICTIONARY ****
1.Insert Word
2.Find Word
3.Delete Word
4.Display
Enter Your Choice :1
Enter Word: john
Enter Meaning: 
john inserted into dictionary at index1
Do you want to continue(y/n)
```

Comment: Where does it crash?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], which anyone can take, compile and run without having to stitch pieces together. Also, make sure it doesn't contain any code that's not necessary to reproduce the crash, like e.g. manual input or unused functions. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### The good news:

It does not crash. It does exactly *what you programmed it to do* ;)

#### Solution

Insert a `std::cin.ignore()` after `std::cin >> word`.

#### Reasons for the problem

You do not ignore the input after reading `word`. `std::cin >> word` will read the characters 'J', 'o', 'h' and 'n' and will then stop, when it encounters the first space in the input stream, which is in your case a new line (what this is depends on the OS, let's assume it's just \n).

But the '\n' is still in the input stream and is the next character to be read!

So `std::getline` starts reading, immediately encouters the '\n' and stops, returning zero characters.